# Total purchase, sales and stock remained for each product using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying to get total purchase, sales and sotck remained for reach product using mysql query which is as follows:

```
select fk_product_id,
(select sum(quantity) from entry_products where status =0 ) as total_purchase,
(select sum(quantity) from entry_products where status =1)as total_sales,
(select sum(quantity) from entry_products where status =0 ) -
(select sum(quantity) from entry_products where status =1) as stock

from entry_products group by fk_product_id
```

Output

```
fk_product_id     total_purchase    total_sales     stock
1                   1700                 660         1040
2                   1700                 660         1040
3                   1700                 660         1040

My Expected Output is
fk_product_id     total_purchase    total_sales     stock
1                   350                  200         150
2                   1100                 460         640
3                   250                  0           250
```

Comment: Good job on sharing your query, and both the output you are getting and the expected output.  You will probably need to give us minimal sample input matching output for us to help you.  You can use conditions like sum(if(status = 0, 0, quantity)) instead of sub-queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need conditional aggregation:

```
select fk_product_id,
       sum(case when status = 0 then quantity else 0 end) as total_purchase,
       sum(case when status = 1 then quantity else 0 end) as total_sales,
       sum(case when status = 0 then quantity else 0 end) - sum(case when status = 1 then quantity else 0 end) as stock
from entry_products 
group by fk_product_id
```

Because MySql evaluates boolean expressions as `1` for `true` or `0` for `false`, the code could be written also like this:

```
select fk_product_id,
       sum((status = 0) * quantity) as total_purchase,
       sum((status = 1) * quantity) as total_sales,
       sum((status = 0) * quantity) - sum((status = 1) * quantity) as stock
from entry_products 
group by fk_product_id
```

Comment: You could use a common table expression to eliminate the duplication in the stock calculation.

Comment: @AllanWind I don't think this is necessary. A decent optimizer would not recalculate the same aggregated columns again. Also a cte would only work only in versions 8.0+ an dthe use of a subquery would not improve anything.

Comment: @AllanWind this is not even valid sql syntax.

Comment: I was thinking more don't repeat yourself (dry) than speed.  Good points too.

Comment: Here is another option (fixed syntax): sum(case when status = 0 then quantity when status = 1 then -quantity else 0 end) as stock

Comment: @AllanWind yes this is syntactically correct, but this will be for sure recalculated because it aggregates a different expression. At least by using the same expressions that were previously been calculated we can hope that they will be reused and not recalculated.

Comment: @forpas Thank you so much. It worked.
Thank you to everyone for contribution